# Does confluent-4.1.1 supports nested avro with ksql cli?

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry, ksqldb

I am working on confluent-4.1.1 with ksql cli. Can I create stream for nested avro data format in this version as i tried with version-5 and it was working fine but no useful link found where mentioned about nested avro schema in confluent-4.1.1

I tried to create stream - 
create stream new_order with(kafka_topic='transition',value_format='avro');

Got error -

Could not fetch the AVRO schema from schema registry. Cannot find correct type for avro type: transition.Value

Comment: @robin-moffatt share link for nested avro in confluent-4.1.1

Comment: solved with the help of https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/1537

Answer (score 0):

Nested Avro support for KSQL was added in version 5.0 of Confluent Platform